# Unable to setup pglogical replication between 2 GCP CloudSQL instances

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-replication

I'm currently trying to setup `pglogical` replication between 2 GCP CloudSQL Postgres instances, in order to quickly migrate data between regions.

I've following the GCP docs[1] by creating a `replicator` user, installing teh `pglogical` extension as that user and performing the required config.

However whenever I create the subscription on the destination service, the status initially goes to `initializing` and then changes to `down. Looking at the` postgres` logs, I can see the following error on the destination side:

```
db=api,user=replicator ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_replication_origin_session_setup
```

I can see the mentioned function in the destination DB, however whenever I try to `GRANT EXECUTE` on it, I get a warning as below.

```
postgres=> \df+ pg_replication_origin_session_setup

      List of functions
   Schema   |                Name                 | Result data type | Argument data types | Type | Volatility | Parallel |     Owner     | Securi
ty |         Access privileges         | Language |             Source code             |                                     Description

------------+-------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------+------------+----------+---------------+-------
---+-----------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------
 pg_catalog | pg_replication_origin_session_setup | void             | text                | func | volatile   | unsafe   | cloudsqladmin | invoke
r  | cloudsqladmin=X/cloudsqladmin    +| internal | pg_replication_origin_session_setup | configure session to maintain replication progress track
ing for the passed in origin
            |                                     |                  |                     |      |            |          |               |
   | cloudsqlsuperuser=X/cloudsqladmin |          |                                     |
(1 row)

postgres=> \du replicator
                 List of roles
 Role name  | Attributes  |      Member of
------------+-------------+---------------------
 replicator | Replication | {cloudsqlsuperuser}

postgres=> GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin_session_setup TO replicator;
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_session_setup"
GRANT
```

Has anyone been able to setup `pglogical` before on CloudSQL? Or seen the above `permission denied` error?

Thanks in advance.
Gavin

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication#configure-your-postgresql-instance